# Visual Studio 2017 ClickOnce - Unable to view published application

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2017, clickonce

I have an application that I'm trying to publish to my website. The error I'm getting is that when done publishing, it says:

[image]

So it looks like it succeeded, but didn't.

My website is located at `www.mywebsite.com`.

In my build properties, under the publish tab, I click `options->deployment`, then set deployment webpage title to `'rdl'`, then I check `automatically generate deployment webpage after every publish`

I then go through the `Publish Wizard`:

Specify the location to publish this application: `ftp://www.mywebsite.com/`

Click next.

Check `From a website`: Specify the url: `http://www.mywebsite.com/`

Check `Yes, this application will be available online or offline`

The final page then states:

```
The application will be published to:
ftp://www.mywebsite.com/

Users will launch this application from:
http://www.mywebsite.com/
```

Click Finish

I am then left with the error described in the image above.

When I go to cPanel (my web host), I am able to see the `Application Files` folder which includes my application folder inside it.My `.deploy` and `.application` file are also located there along with any assets I had.

This `Application Files` folder is on the same level as the `public_html` folder if that matters.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not exactly sure where I'm going wrong!

Comment: If you have got an answer, please update. I am also having the same issue

Comment: Sadly I don't. I was never able to find an answer to this question :(